# How to convert this UTF-8 escaped string from an Amazon MWS response to proper UTF-8?

Tags: php, mongodb, utf-8, simplexml, amazon-mws

In part of an XML Amazon MWS ListOrders response we got an escaped UTF-8 character in one element:

```
<Address><Name>Ram&#xC3;&#xAD;rez Jones</Name></Address>
```

The name is supposed to be **Ramírez**. The diacritic character `í` is UTF-8 character `U+00ED` (`\xc3\xad` in literal; see [this chart](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex) for reference).

However PHP's SimpleXML function mangles this string(which you can see because I simply pasted), transforming it into

> RamÃ­rez Jones

into the editor box here (evidently stackoverflow's ASP.NET underpinnings do the same thing as PHP).

Now when this mangled string gets saved into, then pulled out of MongoDB, it then becomes

> RamÃ-­rez Jones

For some reason a hyphen is inserted there, although believe it or not, if you select the above bold text, then paste it back into a StackOverflow editor window, it will simply appear as `RamÃ­rez` (the hyphen mysteriously vanishes, at least on OS X 10.8.5)!

Here is some example code to show this problem:

```
$xml = "<Address><Name>Ram&#xC3;&#xAD;rez Jones</Name></Address>";
$elem = new SimpleXMLAddressent($xml);
$bad_string = $elem->Name;
echo mb_detect_encoding($bad_string)."\n";
echo $elem->Name->__toString()."\n";
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $elem->Name->__toString());
```

Here is the output from the above sample code, [as run on onlinephpfunction.com's sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com):

> UTF-8
>       RamÃ­rez Jones
>       RamA-rez Jones

How can we avoid this problem? It's really screwing things up.

EDIT:

Let me add that while the name in the XML is supposed to be **Ramírez Jones**, I need to transliterate it to **Ramirez Jones** (strip the diacrtic mark off of the í).

**REVISED FINAL SOLUTION:**

It's different than the correct answer below but this was the most elegant solution that I found. Just replace the last line of the example with this:

`echo iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT', html_entity_decode($xml));`

This works because `"&#xC3;&#xAD;"` are [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

**ALTERNATE SOLUTION**

Strangely, this also works:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><Address><Name>Ram&#xC3;&#xAD;rez Jones</Name></Address>';
$xml= str_replace('<?xml version="1.0"?>', '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>' , $xml);
$domdoc = new DOMDocument();
$domdoc->loadXML($xml);
$xml = iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$domdoc->saveXML());
$elem = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo $elem->Name;
```

Comment: The official PHP documentation page for [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) together with user comments explain everything pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML does not decode the hex entities *and* understand the result as UTF-8, because that's not how XML or UTF-8 actually works. Nevertheless, if Amazon produces such nonsense, you need to correct that error before parsing it as XML.

```
function decode_hexentities($xml) {
  return
    preg_replace_callback(
      '~&#x([0-9a-fA-F]+);~i', 
      function ($matches) { return chr(hexdec($matches[1])); }, 
      $xml
    );
}

$xml = "<Address><Name>Ram&#xC3;&#xAD;rez Jones</Name></Address>";
$xml = decode_hexentities($xml);
$elem = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$bad_string = $elem->Name;
echo mb_detect_encoding($bad_string)."\n";
echo $elem->Name->__toString()."\n";
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $elem->Name->__toString());
```

results in:

```
UTF-8
Ramírez Jones
Ramirez Jones
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because it is encoded twice. The character `í` has the code `U+00ED` and it should be encoded in XML as `&#ED;`.

You can fix its encoding using either:

```
$name = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $elem->Name->__toString());
```

or

```
$name = mb_convert_encoding($elem->Name->__toString(), 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
```

**UPDATE:**

Both ways suggested above work to fix the encoding (they actually convert the encoding of the string from `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1` which incidentally fix the issue at hand).

The solution provided by @Hazzit also works.

The real challenge for both solutions (and for your code) is to detect **if** the received data is encoded in a wrong way and apply these fixes only in that situation, letting the code work correctly when Amazon fixes the encoding issue. I hope they will do it.

#### Stripping the accents with minimum loss of information

After you fix the encoding, in order to replace the accented letters with similar letters from the ASCII subset you must use `iconv()` (because only `iconv()` can help), as you already did in the sample code.

```
$nameAscii = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $name);
```

An explanation of the second parameter can be found in the documentation page of [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php); please also read the user comments.

Comment: If you received that XML from Amazon, your biggest problem is not how to get the correct data but how to automatically find out when the received data is encoded wrong and needs to be fixed to keep your code running well after they fix the issue (hoping they will fix it).

Comment: Both of these work to make it into **Ramírez**, which is what it should be, but subsequently I need to make it into **Ramirez** to submit to an API that does not allow any extended chars. Can you edit your answer to show how it would do that? Thanks. I should've been more clear when I asked the question at first.

Comment: I read the PHP manpage but there is *no* explanation of using multiple character encoding names separated by // in the second argument of the function, like "`ISO-8859-1//ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE`", not in the comments or the main section. Nor is there a list of all the valid character encodings. Nor is there any explanation of what the character encodings mean, or how to unescape values like we're having to do here. All in all it's a terrible manpage! Just sayin'.

Comment: Not quite the appropriate place to learn what a character encoding is. About escaping and unescaping... there is no need for them. A character encoding is just a way to represent a set of symbols (characters), represented by integer positive numbers, using a limited number of bits/bytes. More information and answers to your questions can be found on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Comment: — Thank you, ax, but I definitely understand what a character encoding is. What I do not understand, however, the highly cryptic double-slash syntax of **iconv** (e.g. `ISO-8859-1//ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE`). I did a lot of searching and simply could not find a good manual for this, i.e. one that explains the meaning of **two encodings in a row, separated by double-slashes** preceding the `//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` part. Also, what I meant about "what the character encodings mean" is that the manual doesn't explain which **specific character encoding** is referred to the sometimes ambiguous codes.

Comment: I think I misled you. I read the manual page again now and I see the second parameter of `iconv()` is a single charset, optionally followed by `//TRANSLIT`, optionally followed by `//IGNORE`. I fixed that in my answer some time ago, as you can see. There are no ambiguous codes, there are only valid codes and invalid codes (for the input character encoding). Without `//IGNORE`, `iconv()` quits when it finds a code that is invalid in the input encoding or has no equivalent in the output encoding (and returns a partially converted string). With `//IGNORE` it skips the invalid code and continues.

Comment: PHP's `iconv()` module is just a wrapper of the [GNU `libiconv`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) library. It uses this library and converts the error codes it return (on error) to PHP notices. The complete list of encodings supported by `iconv()` can be found in the documentation page of function [`iconv_open()`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv_open.3.html) and the behaviour of the conversion is described on function [`iconv()`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv.3.html).

Comment: Thank you @axiac. Why do you suppose that iconv accepts a toCode argument with multiple charsets inside, separated by // ? It does seem to change the results and doesn't throw an error. Maybe this is too deep of a question for the comments thread here...

Comment: I didn't suppose this. I wrote it by mistake in my answer. When I realized the error I modified the answer and removed the second encoding. Sorry to point you to a wrong path :-(